# How to make Tail Rec handle more

Tags: java, scala

The below code uses up to much heap space. Can it be improved to handle high number and be quick? Ideally don't want to use any libraries.

```scala
import scala.math.__ 

object MainObject {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    def genv(version: Long): List[Long] = {

      def rec(version: Long, accum: List[Long]): List[Long] = {
       if (version <= 0) accum
       else rec(version - 1, version :: accum)
 }

}
}
       rec(version, List.empty[Long])

println(genv(System.current TimeMillis()))
```

Comment: What is even the point of the code? Also, how do you expect it to consume less space you are literally creating an enormous `List`

Comment: Range .to method doesn't take Long type so I tried to recreate what .to() method was doing with tailrec

Comment: If what you want is to create a lazy range of `Longs` use `LazyList` or `Iterator`, methods like `from`, `range`, `tabulate`, `unfold`, etc may be useful for your real case.

Comment: `Range` supports `Long` just fine e.g. `(0L to 10000)`

Comment: Also, `Range` doesn't have a `to` method, so really not clear what you are trying to do.